# SQL - Select Primary key from sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

Just started SQL about a week ago and I'm wondering why this gives me an error.
If I do Select * at the top I can see the ITEM_NUMBER as well as if I use any other column name but I cannot see this one.

I'm using Oracle and ORDER_DELIVERABLES has ITEM_NUMBER as the Primary Key while DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER.ITEM_NUMBER has it as its PF which I assume is Primary Foreign?

If anyone could help me out and maybe explain a little that would be great.
Thanks!

```
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES
  INNER JOIN DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER 
          ON DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER.ITEM_NUMBER = ORDER_DELIVERABLES.ITEM_NUMBER
)
```

Answer (score 3):

what error does it return?

I suspect this is an ambiguous field error, because using `*` in the `select` part selects the item_number from the 2 tables, so the engine doesn't know which one to take. Try this:

```
SELECT t.it
FROM
(
  SELECT o.ITEM_NUMBER it
  FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES o
      INNER JOIN DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER d ON d.ITEM_NUMBER = o.ITEM_NUMBER
) t
```

As commented, your query could actually be done this way:

```
SELECT o.ITEM_NUMBER
FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES o
      INNER JOIN DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER d ON d.ITEM_NUMBER = o.ITEM_NUMBER
```

Comment: yes, I tryed to *correct only*... but you're right, i'm going to add some informations

Comment: Id he's only selecting the item number, he can replace the join (which is pretty expensive) with an exists clause by just doing `SELECT o.ITEM_NUMBER from ORDER_DELIVERABLES o WHERE EXISTS( SELECT null FROM DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER d WHERE d.ITEM_NUMBER = o.ITEM_NUMBER )`.

Comment: If he really only wants the item numbers, `SELECT DISTINCT item_number FROM digitalproduct_order` would work!

Comment: `SELECT t.ITEM_NUMBER
    FROM
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES o
      INNER JOIN DIGITALPRODUCT_ORDER d ON d.ITEM_NUMBER = o.ITEM_NUMBER
    ) t`

I tried that and I still get an error. "T"."ITEM_NUMBER": invalid identifier

I'm more interested in as to why this specific query doesn't work, I know there are simplier ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, will I still be able to access the other columns if I don't do a SELECT * in the subquery?

Comment: you have to enumerate them one per one, or stipulate the table like this: `ORDER_DELIVERABLES.*` for example. This way you ensure the selected fields come from only one table. How many fields do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in two levels:

1.) Let's fetch the Primary key from ORDER_DELIVERABLES:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES
```

2.) Let's build it into the main query

```
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER
FROM SOME_MAIN_TABLE
WHERE ID = (
    SHOW INDEX FROM ORDER_DELIVERABLES
)
```

This logic is based on MySQL, but I'm sure that if you lookup the Oracle manuals you can find how to access the Primary key from a table without crazy joins :).